# Webmethod not firing after jquery $.post (500 Error)

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net

I have a jquery post that returns a 500 error anytime I attempt to execute a specific webmethod. I have tested out my call post & the actual function that I am attempting to call and both work. I'm not sure why I'm receiving this error when it isn't happening on my other webmethods.

Tests I have run:
1) Check to see if webmethod was incorrect:
I called the webmethod from the codebehind and it ran just fine.

2) Check if I was calling the webmethod incorrectly in the .post:
I changed the URL to call a different function and it worked.

3) Breakpoints:
Breakpoints that I have placed inside of my desired function are not triggering, but when I tested other webmethods with the same .post they would trigger.

What is on my Site.js:

```
    $('#result-table').on('click', '.delete-user-button', function () {

        //var temp = JSON.stringify($(this).data('userid'));

        var obj = {
            recordId: $(this).data('userid')
        };

        $.post({
            url: '/svc/webmethods.aspx/Delete_User_Group',
            data: JSON.stringify(obj),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        })
    })
```

What is on my webmethod.aspx.vb

```
    <WebMethod()>
    Public Shared Function Delete_User_Group(form As String) As BooleanResponse
        Try
            Dim response As New BooleanResponse()
            Dim formFieldList = Get_FormFieldsAsList(form)
            Dim RecordId As String = formFieldList.First.value

            Dim user As New UserMembership(SiteUtils.DefaultConnectionString)
            user.RecordId = RecordId
            user.Delete()
            If user.IsDeleted Then
                response.IsSuccess = True
            Else
                response.IsSuccess = False
                response.Message = "Failed to Delete User"
            End If

            Dim group As New UserMembership(SiteUtils.DefaultConnectionString)
            group.RecordId = RecordId
            group.Delete()
            If group.IsDeleted And response.IsSuccess = True Then
                response.IsSuccess = True
            Else
                response.IsSuccess = False
                response.Message += " Failed to Delete Group"
            End If
            Return response
        Catch ex As Exception
            HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 500
            HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusDescription = ex.Message
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function
```

I am expecting the Delete_User_Group webmethod to fire allowing me to run the instructions.

I am receiving this error:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) [/svc/webmethods.aspx/Delete_User_Group]

**EDIT 1:**
I updated the code to remove the double stringify in my jquery handler. Unfortunately I still received the 500 error.

**EDIT 2:** I did some more testing and was able to get my webmethod to fire. I did this by getting rid of the parameter I was passing.

```
$.post({
       url: '/svc/webmethods.aspx/Delete_User_Group',
       dataType: 'json',
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
})

...

Public Shared Function Delete_User_Group() As BooleanResponse
```

I've been working on it for a while and can't figure out how to properly pass the parameter to my webmethod. For all of the other webmethods I have been doing the same thing and I'm stumped as to why this isn't working.

**ANSWER:** Finally found the error, super beginner so I'm kind of embarrassed.

The error was because the .post that I was using was sending an object with the field name as "recordID" while the webmethod was expecting the argument to come in as "form"

```
Site.js:
        var obj = {
            recordId: $(this).data('userid')
        };

webmethod.aspx.vb:
Public Shared Function Delete_User_Group(form As String) As BooleanResponse
```

In the end I changed the JSON object field to this:

```
Site.js:
        var obj = {
            form: $(this).data('userid')
        };
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You seem to be performing JSON.stringify twice. So  I suspect this is why you get a 500 status. You .NET code may not know how to handle the data you're sending in.

Comment: @Twisty I changed my code to fix that and still had the same error.